# Перенос репозитория с историей

Tags: git, gitlab

появилась необходимость обновления железа на сервере и, как следствие, заказали новый сервак.

У нас имеется несколько проектов по 30-40 гб, не хотелось бы заставлять всех перекачивать.

Вопрос. Как можно перенести реп с всей историей, ветками и тегами, чтобы потом люди просто обновили ссылку на него в условном Fork.
Видел такую реализацию, когда знакомый мигрейтил проект, а мне нужно было лишь через Fork, не помню уже как, но просто вставить новую ссылку, реп фечнулся и не пришлось ничего перекачивать

Нашел способ через:

```
git clone --bare git@git.test.com:my-repo-a.git
git fetch origin
git remote add new-origin git@git.test.com:my-repo-b.git
git push --mirror new-origin
git remote rm origin
git remote rename new-origin origin
```

Но он у меня не взлетел, не дает запушить на стадии пуша миррора. Пишет, что нет правл для форс пуша, но они все выставлены, даже попробовал просто форс пушнуть, все пошло

P.S. Используем SelfHosted Gitlab CE

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял сути происходящего. Если вы обновляете сервак — просто скопируйте все данные со старого сервака на новый (или даже тупо жёсткие диски поменяйте местами), и не надо нигде никакие ссылки менять, не?

Comment: Новые ссд ставим и на новый домен регаем, так не выйдет

Comment: А зачем новый домен-то? Меня не покидает ощущение, что вы решили создать себе проблемы на пустом месте

Comment: У Гитлаб есть функция импорта из гита, битбакета и прочих других. В UI интерфейсе

Comment: *"Новые ссд ставим и на новый домен регаем, так не выйдет"* - ничего из этого не мешает использовать данные из старого гитлаба. Просто целиком скопируйте их на новый ссд, а домен поменяйте в настройках. Собственно разворачивание данных с одного сервера на другом следует проводить не реже, чем раз в неделю при проверке работоспособности бекапов гитлаба (вы же их делаете?). *"Пишет, что нет правл для форс пуша"* - в приведенных командах форс пуш нигде не выполняется. И вообще, не выдумывайте пересказ результата выполнения команд, а приводите его, как есть.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html   ......https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html   и в целом ссылка на раздел  с импортами https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/